# Inverting line order between a string

Tags: python, string

I'm having some difficulty with a script I am writing in python. I hope that someone is able to help me. I would like my program to read lines between a set of characters, reverse the order of the lines and then write them into a new file. In the text below the numbers that follow "G01X" ascend and descend. They range between 0.001 and 149.999. They are separated by the string "G01Y". When "G01Y" appears, their sorting order is inverted. I would like to create a script that makes these value always descend.

Its really a question of inverting the sorting order of every other group A-B, C-D.

The value of G01Y increases by 0.25 every time it appears. Perhaps this would be the best way of identifying the groups. I  have taken a rather clumsy approach and tried to identify 'every other' appearance of G01Y using `[::2]` - I'm sure this is not the best thing.

My code so far:

```
with open('Source.nc') as infile, open('Output.nc', 'w') as outfile:

    do_reverse = False
    lines_to_reverse = []

    strings_A = ("G01Y")
    strings_B = ("G01Y"[::2])

    for line in infile:
        if (x in line for x in strings_A):
           do_reverse = False
           outfile.writelines(reversed(lines_to_reverse))
           outfile.writelines(line)
           continue
        if do_reverse:
          lines_to_reverse.append(line)
          continue
        else:
          outfile.writelines(line)
        if (x in line for x in strings_B):
          do_reverse = True
          lines_to_reverse = []
```

The source code:

```
N10 G17 G21 G90
N20 '2014_12_08_Banding_Test_4_250um_Stepover
N30 M3 S1
N40G00X0.000Y0.000Z17.000
N50 G00X0.001Y0.001Z17.000
N60 G01Z0.000F3900.0
N70 G01X0.251
N80 G01X149.999
N90 G01Y0.251
N100 G01X149.749
N110 G01X149.499Z-8.169
N120 G01X148.249Z-8.173
N130 G01X146.999Z-8.183
N140 G01X145.499Z-8.201
N150 G01X143.999Z-8.226
...
N3130 G01X0.001
N3140 G01Y0.501
N3150 G01X0.251
N3160 G01X0.501Z-15.867
N3170 G01X0.751Z-15.795
N3180 G01X1.251Z-15.639
N3190 G01X1.751Z-15.471
N3200 G01X2.251Z-15.290
...
N6190 G01X149.999
N6200 G01Y0.751
N6210 G01X149.749
N6220 G01X149.499Z-8.166
N6230 G01X147.999Z-8.169
N6240 G01X146.499Z-8.179
N6250 G01X144.749Z-8.201
N6260 G01X143.249Z-8.226
...
N9260 G01X0.001
N9270 G01Y1.001
N9280 G01X0.251
N9290 G01X0.501Z-15.865
N9300 G01X0.751Z-15.792
N9310 G01X1.251Z-15.635
N9320 G01X1.751Z-15.463
N9330 G01X2.251Z-15.280
...
N12320 G01X149.999
N12330 G01Y1.251
N12340 G01X149.749
N12350 G01X149.499Z-8.164
N12360 G01X147.999Z-8.163
N12370 G01X146.249Z-8.173
N12380 G01X144.749Z-8.190
N12390 G01X143.249Z-8.213
...
N15380 G01X0.001
N15390 G01Y1.501
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to put the lines into a `dict` with the negative of their line number as the key. In other words, something like this:

```
lines_to_reverse = {}
line_number = 0

for line in infile:
    line_number += 1
    ....

    # if we're in a section that needs to be reversed
    lines_to_reverse[-line_number] = line
```

Then when you want to print them out:

```
for k in sorted(lines_to_reverse.keys()):
    print lines_to_reverse[k]
```

Other alternatives are certainly possible, like using a `list` like a stack (although using a `deque` would be better performance-wise:

```
lines_to_reverse = []

for line in infile:
    ....
    lines_to_reverse = [line] + lines_to_reverse

for line in lines_to_reverse:
    print line
```

Obviously, I'm not recreating all the logic you need for determining when you're in a particular group or not, but the key concept is figuring out how to reverse a sequence of lines, which has multiple alternatives...